# Change byte array buffer with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I have bytes array in Python that I want to change some value by index

```
arr =b'12345678'
arr[2:] =b'fff'
```

But I got error
`TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment`

Why is that ? how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

byte item assignment with bytearray

```
arr = b'12345678'
arr = bytearray(arr)
arr[2:] = b'fff'
```